# How to matche all the words from a string that starts and ends with double underscore in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
str = "Hello my name is __john__ and i am __30__ years old"
str.scan(/__(.*?)__/)
```

OUTPUT: [["john"], [30]]
Expected result: ["john", 30]

Comment: What is the exact question? Are you facing any problems with the above approach?

Comment: Hi Deepak, i am getting following output
[["john"], [30]]
Expected result: ["john", 30]

Comment: You could use `.flatten` on the result, that would convert it to what you desire

Comment: 5 downvotes on a new member? I guess that's the last time they will log onto StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @aspend mentioned above you will get result just by using .flatten property of array class:

```
<% str = "Hello my name is __john__ and i am __30__ years old"%>
<%=str.scan(/__(.*?)__/).flatten %>
```

Preview:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Nezir

Comment: please vote up if it was useful